# grep in R two strings that differ by one character

Tags: regex, r

I'm having an issue trying to match exactly two different types types of characters with grep in R.
I have two different strings

```
a <- "10-13"  
b <-"+0-2"
```

when I do

```
case1 <- grep("+[0-9]-[0-9]",a, ignore.case=FALSE, perl=FALSE, fixed=FALSE, 
    useBytes=FALSE, invert=FALSE)
```

and

```
case2 <- grep("[0-9]-[0-9]",a, ignore.case=FALSE, perl=FALSE, fixed=FALSE,
    useBytes=FALSE, invert=FALSE)
```

Both `case1` and `case2`  are matched for `a` and `b` (`case1=1`, `case2=1`). However I would like that `case1=integer(0)`  `case2=1` for `a` because it doesn't have the plus symbol at the beginning.
And `case1=1` matched and `case2=integer(0)`  for `b` because it starts with the plus symbol.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your description of your desired output is confusing.  You might try a `^` prefix which makes matching at the beginning of the string explicit.

Comment: so for a the answer should be
case1=integer(0) (nothing)
case2=1 
for b
case1=1
case2=integer(0)

Answer (score 0):

Escape with `\\+` for the first, and indicate that you want two numbers for the second...?

```
sapply(c(a,b),function(s)grepl("\\+[0-9]-[0-9]",s)) # FALSE TRUE
sapply(c(a,b),function(s)grepl("[0-9]{2}-[0-9]",s)) # TRUE FALSE
```

If you just want to test "has a + at the start":

```
sapply(c(a,b),function(s)grepl("^\\+",s))
# 10-13  +0-2 
# FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: @RosanaZF You can use `grep` instead of `grepl` here if you want to. The output of `grepl` is more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the following regex commands.

With or without leading `+`:

```
grep("[0-9]+-[0-9]+", a)
# [1] 1
grep("[0-9]+-[0-9]+", b)
# [1] 1
```

With leading `+`:

```
grep("\\+[0-9]+-[0-9]+", a)
# integer(0)
grep("\\+[0-9]+-[0-9]+", b)
# [1] 1
```